Pantheon on Ubuntu Server 24.04.1
I've got a copy of Ubuntu Server 24.04.1 LTS) set up in a VirtualBox for testing...
It all works well. As a test I wanted to install Pantheon on top of Ubuntu Server and went through the process of adding the repositories, restarting, installing, etc, etc.
The good news is when I boot, I'm asked to log into Pantheon.
The bad news is, I have no network communication. Opening the settins window for Networking, it shows it turned off, but I cannot turn it on.
The weird part is if I open a terminal window, firstly it asks me to log in, and secondly it can find the internet.
Any idea how do I tell Pantheon to connect to the internet?
I added the Pantheon Repositories thusly:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install elementary-desktop


I installed Ubuntu Server v24.0.4.1
I added the Pantheon Repositories thusly:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/stable
sudo apt-get update
And then:
sudo apt-get install elementary-desktop

Sorry about the formatting. This thing evidently doesn't like carriage returns....

This is a Q&A (Question and Answer) and not a forum; answers will be to your question, with comments being from Readers asking for clarifications etc to the OP or Original Poster. Replies should be corrections or edits to your question (which is what is answered) with comments removed once addressed in question. There is formatting available in questions & answers (not in comments which should only be temporary, being soon removed; clearer questions tend to get more attention)  FYI:  It's Ubuntu 24.04.1 (the .1 at end just shows point release or update level; release being 24.04)
